# How do you update multiple rows in subsonic?

Tags: subsonic3

I want to update multiple rows in my SQL database using subsonic but I can't figure out how to do it. What's the easiest way of doing it?

It would be something like this in sql : UPDATE table SET rowItem = 4 WHERE row_item = 3

Answer (score 0):

```
 new (DataBaseName)DB().Update<ClassName>()
                        .Set(x => x.rowItem == 4)
                        .Where(x => x.row_item == 3).Execute();
```